# Difference between symfony2 callbacks and custom validation constraints

Tags: validation, symfony, entity

As far as I understand a **[callback](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Callback.html)** is a constraint that you can customise and set to any field for any type of validation.

A **[custom validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)** overrides the base constraint class (creating any type of validation on any field)

I'm just not sure what the difference is, why would I use one and not the other?
Are there any performance differences too?

Comment: One difference, from the bottom of the callback article: "f you specify your Callback constraint via PHP, then you also have the option to make your callback either a PHP closure or a non-static callback. It is not currently possible, however, to specify a service as a constraint. To validate using a service, you should create a custom validation constraint and add that new constraint to your class."

Comment: Custom Constraint also allows you to run a constraint across multiple properties, say you had 3 fields and you needed to check that the values for these 3 fields were unique, you could use the custom constraint for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't researched the Form Component that much to be aware of any performance differences, but besides that, why you should choose one over the other:

#### Callbacks

- It is meant to customize the whole validation process, not just the Constraint. For instance, you can set where the error needs to be displayed;
- The target is **always** a class, you can't use it on a property;
- You can't reuse it, it is only available on that class/entity.

#### Custom Validator Constraints

- You can reuse it everywhere (as said by @MrGlass, you can even use services as constraint);
- It can be used on a class and property target;
- You can **only** customize when something fails, not what is done after it fails.